# Projections way off on data imported into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have elevation data as a .shp from the USDA ARS and Hi-Res Orthoimages (Mystery Projection (UTM 15N?)) from the USGS website as geoTIFFs (plain NAD 83).

I am trying to project all of the images in NAD1927 MI GeoRef (Meters). OTF projection is on.

The orthoimages are appearing several hundred miles to the East of the elevation data and are rotated about 60 degrees clockwise.

I tried reprojecting the images as well as setting several different Layer CRSs, nothing seems to work.  I am using QGIS 2.8.2

Edit: The "mystery data" is from the USGS Earth Explorer, documentation that came in the file says UTM 15, the zone that the parcel is located in should be 17, and QGIS thinks that the images are in Michigan State Plane Southeast. The MI Georef projection is an oblique Mercator projection which might explain the tilt.  I'll add more specifics about the extent when I return to my computer this afternoon.

Comment: To know which dataset is correctly placed, try setting the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857, add Google or Openstreetmap imagery with the openlayers plugin, then add your datasets. **DON'T** **USE** `Set CRS for Layer`for reprojecting, but `Save As ...`

Comment: Once you do that, add the mystery data's extents to your question, please. And, where did the mystery come from? Have you asked the data provider/searched their website for metadata information?